# Is there a way for autocompleting commands' flags when using OSX terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, autocomplete

I wondered if there is a way/plugin/bashrc_function for autocompleting commands' flags when using OSX terminal.

**Example**
When writing `grep --excl` and pressing `tab` it would autocomplete to `grep --exclude` and then pressing `tab` one more time would autocomplete to `grep --exclude-dir`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there's not much different between bash on OSX and Linux...

You can use the bash `complete` command to configure autocomplete options in bash. You would have to put these in your `.bashrc` file in your home directory you can get to it by typing `cd ~` or `cd $HOME` in the terminal. If there is no `.bashrc` file in your home directory, just create a new empty one and put your calls to `complete` there.

You will have to manually add all possible entries for specific commands, however, though it is conceivable that you could probably build a script to parse out the available options for a command from the `man` page and generate a call to `complete` that includes them.

(Note: I have not used `complete` in bash, personally. I primarily am working in tcsh but it has a similar command though with its own unique syntax and implementation, of course.)

Comment: That would mean I should program a function which parses all the existing flags from all the installed programs, and add those to the `complete` method. But then everytime I open bash it would run the function again, which is useless if the installed programs haven't changed. And even if I could make it run just once, for every new install it should be re-runned. And besides, I wouldn't like flags to mess between different commands, which I think this solution would lead to.

Comment: You could have the script parse all the flags for whatever programs you desire and generate the list of `complete` commands which you could then put in your `.bashrc`. The parsing step would be the longest running portion, and you're right, you only need to run it once. The `complete` commands don't have a large performance overhead.

Comment: The `complete` command understands what command you're running. So if you typed `grep`, it will only use the tab complete rules for the `grep` command. Same for `sed`, `tar`, `ls`, or any other commands you choose to use. bash is smart about this and knows what to do.